# Fortran 90, function, array

Tags: function, fortran

I am a novice in Fortran programming. I have two .f90 files.

fmat.f90

```
function fmat(t,y)
 implicit none
 real::t
 real::y(2)
 real::fmat(2)
 fmat(1) = -2*t+y(1)
 fmat(2) = y(1)-y(2)
end function fmat
```

And, main.f90 looks like:

```
program main
 implicit none
 real::t
 real::y(2)
 real::fmat(2)
 real::k(2)
 t=0.1
 y(1)=0.5
 y(2)=1.4
 k=fmat(t,y)
 write(*,*) k
end program main
```

So, I am expecting 0.3 -0.9. But I keep getting the following error messages:

```
ifort fmat.f90 main.f90

main.f90(13): error #6351: The number of subscripts is incorrect.   [FMAT]
k=fmat(t,y)
--^
compilation aborted for main.f90 (code 1)
```

Any help is appreciated!

!==== EDIT ====

I thank Mark for his answers. I could actually compile the separate files without any error using a "subroutine" approach.

main.f90

```
program main
  implicit none
  real::t
  real::y(2)
  real::k(2)
  t=0.1
  y(1)=0.5
  y(2)=1.4
  call fmat_sub(t,y,k)
  write(*,*) k
end program main
```

fmat_sub.f90

```
subroutine fmat_sub(t,y,k)
  implicit none
  real::t
  real::y(2),k(2)
  k(1) = -2*t+y(1)
  k(2) = y(1)-y(2)
end subroutine fmat_sub
```

Comment: Now try replacing, in `main` the line `call fmat_sub(t,y,k)` with the line `call fmat_sub(t,y)` and see how things go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your declaration, in `main`, of `real::fmat(2)` tells the compiler that `fmat` is an array of reals with rank 1 and length 2. It does not tell it anything about the function `fmat` written in your other file.

One good way to avoid such issues is to use the capabilities of modern Fortran.  Put your subroutines and functions into *modules* and *use-associate* them.  So, change `fmat.f90` to something like

```
module useful_functions

contains
function fmat(t,y)
 implicit none
 real::t
 real::y(2)
 real::fmat(2)
 fmat(1) = -2*t+y(1)
 fmat(2) = y(1)-y(2)
end function fmat

end module useful_functions
```

and modify `main.f90` to something like

```
program main
 use useful_functions
 implicit none
 real::t
 real::y(2)
 real::k(2)
 t=0.1
 y(1)=0.5
 y(2)=1.4
 k=fmat(t,y)
 write(*,*) k
end program main
```

This approach lets the compiler generate *explicit interfaces* for the module functions and allows it to check, at compile time, the match between *dummy arguments* and *actual arguments*.

Since you are a novice I've put some key terms in italics, read about them in your compiler manual or other favourite Fortran documentation.

Another way to solve your problem would be to edit `main.f90` to include the source for function `fmat`, like this:

```
program main
 implicit none
 real::t
 real::y(2)
 real::k(2)
 t=0.1
 y(1)=0.5
 y(2)=1.4
 k=fmat(t,y)
 write(*,*) k

contains

function fmat(t,y)
 implicit none
 real::t
 real::y(2)
 real::fmat(2)
 fmat(1) = -2*t+y(1)
 fmat(2) = y(1)-y(2)
end function fmat
end program main
```

I favour the first approach, it scales much better when your programs and projects get large and the benefits of modularisation start to become necessities rather than nice-to-have, but the second approach is OK for small programs while you are learning the language.

Comment: I love how we refer to features introduced in fortran 90 (~20 years ago) as "*modern*"  :).  Good answer (+1)